# Show all of output but only save matching lines of output

Tags: bash, curl

I would like to monitor the output of a command and save parts of its output as it prints using a filter. Using `grep` would be a way to filter the output but I can only get it to show the matches, but it's not what I want.

In my case I am running `curl` on a list of URLs and would like to see its results, while only saving the results that has a status code of 000 or 200 to a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tee /dev/stderr` to duplicate output.

for example:

```
seq 9 | tee /dev/stderr | grep "[42]" > result.txt
```

`seq 9` outputs 1 to 9, `tee /dev/stderr` duplicate output to `stderr`, `grep "[42]"` to filter output and save to file `result.txt`

or, using process substitution

```
seq 9 | tee >(grep "[42]" > result.txt)
```

We can treat `>(grep "[42]" > result.txt)` as a file. So `tee >(grep "[42]" > result.txt)` will duplicate output to `stdout` and save to this special file. But the file is a process, which is `grep "[42]" > result.txt`.